# Dropdownlist AutoPostBack causes client table form disappear

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am using an `asp:DropDownList` that has 2 option forms(Windows and Linux) to fill in.

If the user selects Windows then the Windows form shows up. If user Select Linux then the Linux form shows up.

They are both `style="display: none;"` in the beginning until the user selects one of them. I use a Javascript function to handle the selections.

If the user fills out some info in the Windows form but realizes that he/she is in wrong form, then he/she can switch to the Linux form however the information he/she filled in the Windows form is still there even it changed back to `style="display: none;"`.

I want all data in the textboxes cleared and `<select>` option go back to original selected if the user switches to a different form. I tried setting the AutoPostBack to true to refresh it but the client side form shows up then suddenly disappears because of the page refresh.

I know one of the ways to clear out textbox values is `document.getElementById("id").value = "";` in Javascript but I have too many textboxes in the form.

What is the best way to clear the textboxes?

Comment: You may want to look into form reset https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement.reset?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2Fform.reset

Comment: Use jQuery $("input[type='text']").val("") to clear all text boxes

Comment: @malkam it worked. Now what about all `<select>` that change back to original selected?

Comment: Set AutoPostBack to false and do everything in client side itself.

Comment: What do you mean do everything in client side itself?

Comment: Nevermind, I use `$("select").prop("selectedIndex", 0);` and it worked

Answer (score 0):

To clear all input textboxes, I use `$("input[type='text']").val("")`.
To return all select option back to original selected, I use `$("select").prop("selectedIndex", 0);`.